# Vba compare date columns in Loop

Tags: excel, vba, date, compare

How can I compare date columns? I have the the dates in a format 'dd/mm/yyyy' and the following code, however it just compares days, not months and years:

```
For j = 13 To lCol Step 2

 For i = 2 To lRow

         If Year(Cells(i, 10).Value) > Year(Cells(i, j).Value) Then Cells(i, j).Font.Color = vbRed
         If Month(Cells(i, 10).Value) > Month(Cells(i, j).Value) Then Cells(i, j).Font.Color = vbRed
         If Day(Cells(i, 10).Value) > Day(Cells(i, j).Value) Then Cells(i, j).Font.Color = vbRed
 Next i

Next j
```

[image]

Comment: Can You show here some of those dates?

Comment: 15/11/2018
17/12/2018
24/10/2018
29/10/2018
29/10/2018
30/11/2018
25/09/2018
12/11/2018

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Why do you first compare year, then month and then day? In this case your font will be red if any of the conditions are true. You can simply compare `Cells(i,10).Value > Cells(i,j).Value`

Comment: Normally, dates, like numbers, are right aligned. Most of your 'dates' are just text. So start by converting those into *real* dates and your work will be greatly simplified.

Comment: I did Michael,......  Dim l As Integer
     Columns(10).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy "
     
     For k = 13 To lastCol Step 2
        Columns(k).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
     Next k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each pair of cells you are performing three separate comparisons, year vs year, month vs month and day vs day. But as you have noted, that is not the correct way to compare dates. It is easy to see that 28/09/2017 is before 17/11/2018 although your way would indicate the contrary because of the day comparison.

Instead you should do only one comparison, between the complete date values. Thanks to Excel's way to store dates and times, this becomes simply:

```
    If Cells(i, 10).Value > Cells(i, j).Value Then Cells(i, j).Font.Color = vbRed
```

Date values are stored as a serial number of days after 31.12.1899, so day 1 is 1.1.1900. How the dates are displayed is determined by the cells formatting.

---

As a side note, the time of the day is represented by the fractional part between two successive day numbers, so 06:00 on 1.1.1900 is represented by 1.25

If your cells do not only hold dates but also times, and you do not want that the times affect the comparison, then you must round down the date and time values as a preparation for the comparison.

There are no VBA functions for rounding, but we can use the worksheet function `RoundDown()` to eliminate the time part of the cell values. For example:

```
    d1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(Cells(i, 10), 0)
    d2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(Cells(i, j), 0)
    If d1 > d2 Then Cells(i, j).Font.Color = vbRed
```

---

Edit after your comment:

> 'If Cells(i, 10).Value > Cells(i, j).Value Then Cells(i, j).Font.Color = vbRed'...It just compared the days, not months and years.

I prepared a test case, where the dates are in the table as actual date values. The test data includes cases for day difference, month difference and year difference.

In addition I changed the formula to use black text color if the test condition is not true. This only to be explicit regarding the color and not to rely on preformatted black only color.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 2 To 9
        If CDate(Cells(i, 2).Value) > CDate(Cells(i, 4).Value) _
          Then Cells(i, 4).Font.Color = vbRed _
          Else Cells(i, 4).Font.Color = vbBlack
    Next i
End Sub
```

The result is as follows:

[image]

Afterwards, it has become clear that your data is a mix of actual date values (serial date numbers) and dates in textual format. I recommend that you convert all textual format dates to actual date data.

Comment: 'If Cells(i, 10).Value > Cells(i, j).Value Then Cells(i, j).Font.Color = vbRed'...It just compared the days, not months and years.

Comment: thanks Tom but I have    13/12/2016 00:00  17/12/2018 13<17 !!


19/12/2016 00:00  24/10/2018 19<24 !!

Comment: I did, I did by ' Columns(10).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy "  '. Doesnt help.

Comment: @NData I made a revision to my code, should work with both textual dates and actual dates.